# What happen to the segment table of a process if a segment is relocated?

Tags: memory-management, system, memory-segmentation

Suppose the system use only segmentation, no paging. What happen to the segment table if a segment is swapped out and relocated? Is it going to have a new segment number? What happen to the old entry in the table?

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on what the hardware provides and how the OS and applications use that.

On the x86, the segment descriptor tables (global and local) have 8192 entries. Segments described in them can be marked as not present and then as present again.

As long as there's free space in the table, there's no need to move or remove segment descriptors, which would change the segment selector (what you call *segment number*).

But if the segment selector changes (the segment selector contains the segment position (index) within the segment table), then any register or memory variable that holds the segment selector needs to be updated. Updating segment selectors in program state has its cost and may be prohibitive. To simplify matters, the OS may require that no other software manipulate with segment selectors. This would make it easy for the OS to update segment selectors, it wouldn't need to keep track of segment selectors in app's memory, it would only need to take care of app's segment registers.

However, the x86 may have multiple local segment descriptor tables, one per app. In this case 8192 segments per app is plenty and so running out of unique segment selectors is less of an issue and there's lesser need to compact/defragment segment descriptor tables.

Other hardware may have other features or restrictions. Like I said, it depends.